# Getting text boxes to move with text

Tags: pages, iwork, text

I have added a number of text boxes to an iWork Pages document. When I want to paste in additional text -- i.e. a methodology section at the beginning -- the text boxes do not move with the text, rather stay on the same page where they were inserted. How can I get them to move with the text?

Answer (score 1):

Open the `Inspector` and select the textbox whose behavior you want to alter. Go to the `Object placement` tab (third icon from left on the top icon row in the Inspector) and choose `Inline (moves with text)`.